# mySQL sorting ASCII as INT

Tags: mysql

In a SQL table there is a `client_num` column declared as `char(5)`. When I sort the table by `client_num` with `ASC` it will have the typical ASCII sort.

```
1  
10    
100   
11  
110
```

How to sort `client_num` as an `INT` while keeping the column still a type of `char(5)`?

EDIT

The above mentioned `SQL order string as number` has quite extensively answers. This question is simple and has straight answers. Though it is a duplicate. But it helps me very quickly.

Comment: try `.. ORDER BY client_num+0` **or** `.. ORDER BY CAST(client_num AS UNSIGNED)`

Comment: doesn't work. What should `+0` do ?

Comment: `MySQL` converts a string to numeric type when added zero like above. You could try the second option too.

Comment: Ok - I was to fast. It`s for casting AND it works perfect !!!

Comment: If you post an sep. answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You could `cast` the column to an integer:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY CAST(client_num AS INT)
```

Comment: Casting is the solution, yes. What is the difference here between `UNSIGNED` and `INT` ?

Comment: INT can be -ve, unsigned cannot

Comment: @Ben `unsigned` has only non-negative numbers, while `int`s can be negative.

Comment: well - stupid that question. So mySQl is finally doing the same cast.

Comment: To whom it may concern :  CAST(client_num as `INT`) brings up a syntax error whlie CAST(client_num as `UNSIGEND`) not. Thats maybe a question of mySQL versions, don't know.